# Inclined plane, circular motion and the friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, friction, free-body-diagram

Suppose we have a cylinder on an inclined plane of mass $m$ and radius $R$ moving without sliding (so that $\varepsilon = a/R$). Why is the friction $F$ causing the circular motion sometimes lower than $F' = f \cdot N$, where $N$ is a normal force and $f$ the friction coefficient? ($F \le f \cdot N$)

Comment: this sounds like a 'homework' question.

Comment: But it is *not*. It simply wasn't sufficiently explained to us.

Comment: Thats OK, either way! Do you have a diagram for it? What are the parameters "$\epsilon$" and "$a$" ?

Comment: You mean some drawing of the situation? As for parameters, well, as ordinarily - circular and linear acceleration.

Comment: Usually an $\alpha$ and not an $\varepsilon$ is used to represent angular (circular) acceleration

Answer (score 1):

It's like that because the rotation without sliding is caused by static friction, not the kinetic one. Thus $T \le f N$. On the other hand, while if the cylinder is sliding, we take the kinetic friction.

Comment: It doesn't specify what type of friction it is.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a free body diagram for the object. You will see that this friction $F$ is the *only* force that attacks at the edge. This is the *only* force that gives a torque.

Since it isn't balanced by any other torques, this is the reason for the accelerating rotation.

The size of this force $F$ doesn't matter - as long as it exists, it will cause a torque.